# When will Git do successful merge vs conflict?

Tags: git

If I have a new clean project (master) and I add a new file which contains :

<kbd>Master : test.txt</kbd>

```
"123"
```

Now I'm creating a new forked branch named "MyBranch", and then I change the content of the file:

<kbd>MyBranch : test.txt</kbd>

```
"193"
```

Now I want to merge `Mybranch --> Master`,

At this situation, I don't know if it will be a success merge or a conflict.
I've seen situations where there is a conflict and when there is a successful merge but still didn't find the golden rule.

**Question**

When does git raise a conflict vs successful merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [eftshift0 says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672894/1256452), though not in these same words, the trick here is that there are not two but *three* inputs to a merge.

You described your process as:

- create a new commit on `master`
- create a new branch `MyBranch`
- create a new commit on `MyBranch`
- run:

  ```
  git checkout master
  git merge MyBranch
  ```

But that's not exactly how development tends to go.  It's usually more like: *create three branches, start working on them, create six more, work on some of those, delete some, create others, work on several for a while, and then—eventually—check one out and run `git merge` on another*.  This more-chaotic work-flow results in a more complex input to the merge process, which—as I mentioned above—really consists of *three* commits.

Of these three commits, *you* get to choose only *two*.  The third one, Git picks for you automatically.

Let's take a moment to review the process of creating a new commit, with drawings.  You:

```
git checkout somebranch
<edit various files>
git add <some edited files>
git commit
```

The `checkout` step populates your index—your proposed next commit, more or less—and your work-tree with all the files from the commit that's at the current *tip* of branch `somebranch`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- somebranch
```

(where each letter stands in for an actual commit hash ID).  The parent of the latest commit `H` is commit `G`; `G`'s parent is `F`, and so on, backwards, down the line of commits that are "on" (contained within) the branch.

When you edit the files, you change the work-tree copy.  You then have to `git add` those to copy those changes back into the index—`git commit` uses the index (the proposed commit, with files in their special Git-ified freeze-dried state) rather than the work-tree (files in their normal everyday form, usable by regular non-Git programs).  The last step, `git commit`, packages up the index copies of all the files—not just the ones you changed, but also *all* the *unchanged* files that were in the index because of commit `H`—and stores them into a new commit, where they're frozen for all time so that any time in the future you can come back to the new commit.

Let's call this new commit `I`.  `I`'s parent is going to be `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- somebranch
            \
             I
```

The *last* step of `git commit` is to update the *name* `somebranch` so that it points to commit `I` instead of to commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- somebranch
```

(and we don't need the kink in the drawing any more).

So, with your particular process, the branch you chose was `master`, and you added a new commit:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

Then you created a new branch *name*.  By default, this new name *also* points to commit `I`.  Commits up through `I` are now on (contained within) *both* branches:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master, MyBranch
```

Now we need one more item to our drawings.  How does Git know which branch *name* to use here?  The answer is that Git attaches the special name `HEAD`, in all capitals like this, to one of the branch names.  That's the branch you're "on", in `git status`'s description when it says `on branch master` or `on branch MyBranch`.  Let's say you create and get onto `MyBranch` so that we have:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master, MyBranch (HEAD)
```

Now you create another new commit.  This gets a big ugly hash ID, but we'll just call it `J`.  As before, Git will make the new commit from whatever is in your index, so you edit files, `git add` them to copy them back into the index, and `git commit` to make `J`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
               \
                J   <-- MyBranch (HEAD)
```

(Note that `HEAD` remains attached to the updated branch.)

It's now *possible* to run `git checkout master; git merge Mybranch`—but this merge is not very interesting.  It's too trivial.  There will never be any merge conflict here.  In fact, by default, `git merge` will notice that no *merging* is required and do a *fast-forward* instead.  You'd have to run `git merge --no-ff` to force it to make a real merge (which would go well).

Instead of making a merge right now, first, let's make a new commit on `master`.  Actually, just to make the merge get letter `M`, let's make *two* commits on `master`, so that we have:

```
                K--L   <-- master (HEAD)
               /
...--F--G--H--I
               \
                J   <-- MyBranch
```

Now when we run `git merge MyBranch`, Git has to do some real work.

The first part lies in finding the three input commits:

- One of those three commits is the one you're on right now—commit `L`, or `master`, or `HEAD` (both names, plus the raw hash ID, select that particular commit).  That particular commit's files will be in your index and work-tree, with no changes in the index or work-tree (`git merge` checks that this is the case and in general won't let you start the merge process with a "dirty" index or work-tree).
- One of those three is the commit you named: in `git merge MyBranch`, you've named commit `J`.
- The last commit—the one you don't get to choose—is what Git calls the *merge base*, and it's the *common starting point* from which the two branches diverged.  Because of the way we've been drawing these, it's easy to see which commit that is: it's commit `I`.

  When we start at commit `L` and work backwards (as Git does), we enumerate commits `L`, then `K`, then `I`, then `H`, and so on.  Meanwhile, when we start at commit `J` and work backwards, we enumerate commits `J`, then `I`, then `H`, and so on.

  The shared commits are commit `I`, `H`, `G`, `F`, and so on, but the *best* shared commit is the last of these, or commit `I`.  So commit `I` is the merge base.

Now that `git merge` has found its three inputs, its main work starts:

- Compare commit `I`—or rather, the snapshot in it—to commit `L`'s snapshot.  Whatever is different here is stuff *we* changed on `master`:

  ```
  git diff --find-renames <hash-of-I> <hash-of-L>
  ```
- Compare commit `I` to commit `J`.  Whatever is different here is stuff *they* (ok, "we") changed on `MyBranch`:

  ```
  git diff --find-renames <hash-of-I> <hash-of-J>
  ```
- *Combine* the results of these two comparisons.
- Apply the combined changes to the snapshot in commit `I`.

If all goes well, the combined changes—those that took the snapshot from `I` to `L`, plus those that took it from `I` to `J`—are now in both the index and work-tree copies of every file, and `git merge` commits the result, as if by `git commit`, but making a commit that remembers *both* `L` *and* `J`:

```
                K--L
               /    \
...--F--G--H--I      M   <-- master (HEAD)
               \ ___/
                J   <-- MyBranch
```

The fact that the merge used commit `I` is not recorded directly, but is implied: the merge base of commits `L` and `J` is `I`, and always will be, forever, because every single bit of information inside any commit is frozen for all time.  The facts are that `L`'s parent is `K` and `K`'s is `I`, for instance: those facts cannot be changed.  `M`'s parents are now `L` and `J` and those cannot be changed.  No part of any commit can be changed, ever: at most, we can make new and improved (and different) commits and just *stop using* the old ones, but we cannot change the old ones.

You get merge conflicts when things *don't* go well.  For instance, if the diff from `I` to `J` says to change line 10 of file `test.txt` from `ABC` to `XYZ`, and the diff from `I` to `L` says to change line 10 of file `test.txt` from `ABC` to `AEIOU`, those changes conflict.  Git will:

- leave *all three* input files in the index (in special high-numbered *staging slots*, which we won't go into here), and
- leave a messy, merge-conflict version of the file in the work-tree, where you can see and work on/with it.

The merge isn't *ended*, but neither is it *complete*.  The fact that there's an unfinished merge is now recorded in two places:

- in the index, because there are nonzero staging slots occupied; and
- in a file containing the hash ID of commit `J`, so that the eventual merge "make a commit" step knows which hash ID to include as the other parent.  (The first parent `L` hash ID is available via `HEAD` as always.)

Your job becomes: *Produce a correct combination for this file, and write it into the index at staging-slot-zero to announce that this file is resolved*.  The `git add` command will take care of the second part—the writing to the index—but you have to come up with the correct *content* on your own, or with the help of a merge tool.

Once you have resolved all conflicts, you run:

```
git merge --continue
```

or:

```
git commit
```

which both do the same thing in this case: `git merge --continue` makes sure there's an in-progress merge that can be finished, and if so, literally just runs `git commit` (at the moment anyway—the Git-for-Windows people keep sticking one command inside another, rather than running another, because Windows apparently takes hours ⏱ ... ok, tenths-of-seconds? ... to chain one command to another, vs the microseconds on Linux).

Answer (score 3):

git raises a conflict when there have been two edits across different branches in the same section of code.

In your situation, because you only made one edit in `Mybranch`, when you merge, there are no conflicts.

If there was a new commit on Master where I changed the text to "987" *and committed* that code BEFORE you attempt the merge, then we would have a conflict.

Helpful resource: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge

Comment: so can I say that if the line in the target branch  is not pristine ( i.e. dirty ) , then a conflict will occur.  right ?  what if you also change it to `123` , same value , but still dirty , will it raise a conflict ?

Comment: That is a good assumption, correct. Even if you changed the value back to 123, git looks at the metadata of commits, and will realize that there exists a single commit that changed the value of that line (i.e. made it dirty) -- so it will raise a conflict.

Comment: wait.... continuing your example , in the answer , even if you changed a different line , and havent touched the "123" line , will it still raise conflict , when I'm about to merge my branch to you ? i mean is it about "line has changed" or "  file has changed" ... ?

Comment: so, its a bit more granular than that -- git will scan and identify changes  on groups of lines called "hunks". If you do `git add -p`, this will show you exactly how git will identify and find changes.

I can imagine how this might be confusing, but if you are still confused, you might benefit from trying to understand more deeply how the merging process works.

Answer (score 2):

In general terms, conflicts will arise when, having two branches with a certain common ancestor, each one of the branches has a different set of changes for a given number of lines.

So.... if you have a common ancestor A, then branches B and C and from A to B you removed 5 lines from a file... and between A and C you modified any of those five lines, you will get a conflict. There are plenty of kinds of conflicts. Modified 5 lines one way, modified those same five lines another way.. you merge, boom! There are other kinds of conflicts like: edit 5 lines on one file... removed the file on another branch. Merge: boom!

If you have a set of changes on one branch and on the other branch there are no changes, there will be no conflict.